# Why is Register-ScheduledJob not running for me?

Tags: powershell, triggers, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I am facing issues with Register-ScheduledJob. To investigate, I wrote a simple command but not sure what am I doing wrong.

```
$t = New-JobTrigger -Daily -At "2:49 PM"
Register-ScheduledJob -Name OpenFile1 -ScriptBlock {Start notepad} -Trigger $t
```

The run creates the output and status xmls and it does not have any errors. Can someone help
[image]

[image]

Ideally, a new notepad file should open at the specified time but nothing happens

Comment: If you look in task planer, the scheduled task is created with the option "run whether user is logged on or not", which doesn't permit interactive processes. For that you need "run only when user is logged on". Research how to create a scheduled job for the current user.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @zett42, the problem was with the user who is running the job. I was able to fix the issue using Scheduled Task instead of Scheduled Job

```
 $t = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At $time
 action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Test\DailyMessage.txt"
 Register-ScheduledTask -Action $action -taskname OpenFile -Trigger $t
```

Worked like a charm. Thanks @zett42